# Using LIME for explanation of deep neural net for fraud detection

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, lime

I have built a deep neural network which classifies fraudulent transactions. I am trying to use LIME for explanation, but am facing an error from the `interpretor.explain_instance()` function.

The complete code is as follows:

```
import lime
from lime import lime_tabular

interpretor = lime_tabular.LimeTabularExplainer(
    training_data=x_train_scaled,
    feature_names=X_train.columns,
    mode='classification'
)

exp = interpretor.explain_instance(
    data_row=x_test_scaled[:1], ##new data
    predict_fn=model.predict,num_features=11
)
xp.show_in_notebook(show_table=True)
```

This throws the error:

---

```
--
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_33/1730959582.py in <module>
      1 exp = interpretor.explain_instance(
      2     data_row=x_test_scaled[1], ##new data
----> 3     predict_fn=model.predict
      4 )
      5 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/lime/lime_tabular.py in explain_instance(self, data_row, predict_fn, labels, top_labels, num_features, num_samples, distance_metric, model_regressor)
    457                     num_features,
    458                     model_regressor=model_regressor,
--> 459                     feature_selection=self.feature_selection)
    460 
    461         if self.mode == "regression":

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/lime/lime_base.py in explain_instance_with_data(self, neighborhood_data, neighborhood_labels, distances, label, num_features, feature_selection, model_regressor)
    180 
    181         weights = self.kernel_fn(distances)
--> 182         labels_column = neighborhood_labels[:, label]
    183         used_features = self.feature_selection(neighborhood_data,
    184                                                labels_column,

IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding `labels=(0,)` in `exp = eplainer.explain_instance()` might resolve your issue.

```
exp = interpretor.explain_instance(
data_row=x_test_scaled[:1], ##new data
predict_fn=model.predict,
num_features=11,
labels=(0,)
)
```

I had a similar issue with breast cancer data trying to predict benign or malignant tumors. The column that contains the recorded sample is titled `benign_0_malignant_1` with either 0 or 1 placed in each row.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are passing in a 2D array, but [according to the docs](https://lime-ml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lime.html#lime.lime_tabular.LimeTabularExplainer.explain_instance) `explain_instance()` is expecting the instance as a 1D array.

Note that a single-row slice from a 2D array is itself 2D:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])
>>> arr[:1]
array([[1, 2]])
```

The other issue is the prediction function, which is expected to produce an array of probabilities, not a single prediction. Again, the docs explain (my emphasis):

> `classifier_fn` – classifier prediction **probability** function, which takes a numpy array and outputs prediction probabilities. For ScikitClassifiers , this is `classifier.predict_proba`.

To fix these things, use a simple index into `x_test_scaled` instead of a slice, and pass `model.predict_proba` as the prediction function:

```
exp = interpretor.explain_instance(data_row=x_test_scaled[0],
                                   predict_fn=model.predict_proba,
                                   num_features=11
                                   )
```

Comment: Hi @kwinkunks I tried what you suggested and now the new error is as follows: "IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1".Any suggestion would be really nice.

Comment: Not sure... what's the shape of `x_test_scaled`? Are you asking for index of 0 or 1? Main thing is to make sure you're passing in a 1D array, so check its size in the REPL before giving it to `explain_instance()`.

Comment: shape of x_test_scaled is (27960, 11). and while passing the data point to the explain_instance() function i used  x_test_scaled[1] which has a shape (11,)

Comment: Maybe just double check, eg print the shape again right before you access it, or share the entire error message to show exactly what is throwing it.

Comment: I rechecked and the dimensions are the same as i mentioned earlier.The complete error code is:
IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1"

Comment: Show all of the *entire* error message by editing your post.

Comment: Hi,I have added the entire error message,please have a look.Thanks

Comment: I read the docs again and you have to pass a prediction function that produces probabilities. I edited my answer accordingly.